# Saving canvas with CanvasRenderingContext2D filter

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, todataurl

I have the problem with saving photo with CanvasRenderingContext2D.filter. When I connect to video and try to take a shot without any filters, it saves normally. However, after adding some filters to canvas, it is saving as HTM file or return previous photo without filters if it was made. The weird is, that while downloading that screenshot manually by clicking on it, it does have own toDataUrl, downloads normally and contains filter but while saving it using toDataUrl, it still doesn't see that picture. 
What should I do to save photos with these filters?

Here is the piece of my code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');       
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');  
var video = document.getElementById("video");

document.getElementById("snapshot").addEventListener("click", function() {
            if ($('video').hasClass('blur')) {
                context.filter ="blur(2px)";
            }
            else {
            context.filter= "";
            }
              context.drawImage(video, 0, 0);
      });
      
document.getElementById("download").addEventListener("click", function() {
              download.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
              };
```

```css
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(3px);
     -moz-filter: blur(3px);
      -ms-filter: blur(3px);
       -o-filter: blur(3px);
          filter: blur(3px);
}
```

```html
<video id="video" autoplay></video>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<button id="download" download="picture" href=""></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Edit] : This bug has [been fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1307740) in FF52+** (current latest Nightly)
I let the answer and its workaround in case it helps someone some time.

---

This seems to be a bug in Firefox with filter-functions. Chrome 54 seems to handle it just right.

When a filter-function is passed as the value of `ctx.filter`, FF does taint the canvas, making all export methods unavailable (`toDataURL` included).

However, it seems pretty happy with svg filters, so one workaround, until [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311274) is fixed, is to use an [svg filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/filter) along with the `url(#yourSVGFilter)` value type.

```js
var img = new Image();
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext('2d');
document.body.appendChild(c);

btn.onclick = function() {
  var i = new Image();
  i.src = c.toDataURL();
  document.body.appendChild(i);
};

img.onload = function() {
  c.width = this.naturalWidth;
  c.height = this.naturalHeight;
  // this doesn't taint the canvas
  ctx.filter = 'url(#blurMe)';

  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}

img.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
img.src = 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png';
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <filter id="blurMe">
    <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="2" />
  </filter>
</svg>

<button id="btn">call toDataURL()</button><br>
```

(And a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kaiido/0cby7o4m/) that reproduces the problem for curious)