# SecurityError when calling getImageData on canvas with filter applied

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to generate a falloff texture for noise generation, in order to achieve that I need to produce a smooth gradient for an arbitrary drawn shape. I'm doing it using gaussian blur in html5 canvas. For some reason after applying the filter, even if I remove it later, when I'm trying to getImageData I'm getting SecurityError. Now I'm aware of what it means, but it beats me why on earth it gets thrown here, as image is generated on the fly and there's nothing cross-origin here. Also for some reason, it only happens of Firefox, while it works perfectly on Chrome.

So yeah, WTH?

See the example below.

```js
var canvas = document.createElement("CANVAS");
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 1024, 1024);
ctx.fillStyle = "black";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 1024, 1024);

ctx.filter = "blur(20px)";
ctx.fillStyle = "white";
ctx.fillRect(30, 30, 200, 100);
ctx.filter = "none";

var img = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, 200, 200);
for(var i = 0; i < img.data.length; i+=4)
 img.data[i] = 255;
ctx.putImageData(img, 0,0);
```

Comment: Have you checked bugzilla for same or similar issue?

Comment: It has already been filed by yours https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1311274 and fixed in latest releases.

Comment: Ps: duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40120212/saving-canvas-with-canvasrenderingcontext2d-filter/40124813#40124813 which needs an upvote to be able to close this question....